# Unable to locate package hdf5

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install hdf5 on Ubuntu 16.04. But the output error is always 'Unable to locate package hdf5'. I have seen many questions similar to mine. But each solution doesn't fit me. So sorry to ask one more similar question. I have tried:

1. find the correct repository and use `sudo add-apt-respository`.
2. Have tried `sudo apt-get update`.

All these solutions don't work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you mis-spelling the name? `htf5` is not the same as `hdf5`

Comment: What command are you using to install?  According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/hdf5-tools it should be `hdf5-tools`  and it is in the default repos.  The install should be `sudo apt install hdf5-tools`

Comment: SO sorry. The name is hdf5

Answer (score -1):

Head on over to https://www.pkgs.org and search for `hdf5`. There are currently no packages for debian so download the CentOS 6 `rpm` archive. Take care to download the package built for your cpu architecture.

Then install `rpm` and `alien` by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rpm alien
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Which will install a useful program called alien that can be used to convert between`.rpm`, `.deb` and `.tgz` archive formats. Having installed `alien` now head on over to the directory where your downloaded archive is at.

To convert the package archive to `.deb` do the ff, changing the string in quotes to the name of the package you've downloaded;

```
sudo alien --to-deb "hdf5-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.rpm"
```

Now that you have a debian archive you can install it using `dpkg`

```
dpkg -i hdf5-1.8.5.patch1-10.el6.i686.deb # chage archive name to your .deb archive's name
```

Then to check and fix if any dependencies are broken,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

P.S. alien binaries have always got some risk associated with them. One should always run binaries compiled and packaged for one's own system spec, or build them natively from source code. This has helped me when I was on a tight schedule but I can't say it's the safest means of porting a package.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
When I follow your instructions. I have another problem.
After I run the command
       dpkg -i hdf5_1.8.5.patch1-11_amd64.deb     
The error returns as 
    Errors were encountered while processing: hdf5_1.8.5.pathch1-11_amd64.deb

Comment: That is always a possibilty when using `alien`, hopefully you've not broke your system. BTW Isn't `hdf5` in `hdf5-tools` ? You can install the later by `sudo apt-get install hdf5-tools hdf5-helpers`. Checked my Kali also and there are only these two packages.